# Using AngularJs dynamic directives for custom view

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-directive

I'm using a server side generated JSON to populate a custom view using different directives with Angular 1.2.29. I have a couple of questions regarding what is the proper way a doing this considering performance and good practices.

- 5 different types of directive will be involved for about 30 items
- The JSON will stay the same about 90% and it's a bit bad to have to regenerate all the DOM elements between user tab switch.
- I want to avoid creating watches but in since I'm using 1.2.X should I consider using [angular-once](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once)
- Since I'm going to reuse the same directive couple of time should I consider [cloneAttachFn](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage)

`function processItems(items) {
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
          switch(item.type) {
            case 'directive1':
              var newDirective = angular.element('<directive-one></directive-one>');
              newDirective.attr('value', item.value);
              var compiledHtml = $compile(newDirective)(scope);
              element.append(compiledHtml);
              break;
            case 'directive2':
              var newDirective = angular.element('<directive-two></directive-two>');
              newDirective.attr('value', item.value);
              var compiledHtml = $compile(newDirective)(scope);
              element.append(compiledHtml);
              break;
          }
        })
      }`

I created a Plunker to show you guys my current approach. Comments and answers are very welcome! https://plnkr.co/edit/Za4ANluUkXYP5RCcnuAb?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been through this problem many times when generating dynamic filter type functionality.  Your code works but I would argue it's over engineered and not very readable.  GenericItems directive isn't needed.  I would try and move functionality to the view and make it clear what happens as the type changes.  [Here is my solution as a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/znQKmj?p=preview)

**Controller**

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl as app">
    <p>{{app.name}}</p>
    <button ng-click="app.add1()">Directive 1</button>
    <button ng-click="app.add2()">Directive 2</button>
    <button ng-click="app.remove()">Remove</button>
    <div ng-repeat="item in app.items">
      <directive-one value="item.value" ng-if="item.type==='directive1'"></directive-one>
      <directive-two value="item.value" ng-if="item.type==='directive2'"></directive-two>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function() {

  var vm = this;
  vm.items = [];

  vm.name = 'Dynamic directive test';
  vm.add1 = function() {
    vm.items.push({type: 'directive1', value: Math.random()})
  };

  vm.add2 = function() {
    vm.items.push({type: 'directive2', value: Math.random()})
  };

  vm.remove = function() {
    vm.items.pop();
  };
});

app.directive('directiveOne', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      value: '='
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<p>d1: {{value}}</p>'
  }
});

app.directive('directiveTwo', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      value: '='
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<p>d2: {{value}}</p>'
  }
});
```